# Getting the size of a UIViewController's view after rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a UIViewController with a bunch of subviews that I need to lay out in a different order if the iPad is in portrait or landscape mode. I'd like to be able to grab the size that the UIViewController's view is going to transform into after the rotation, so that I can calculate the new set of frames for my subviews. However, I haven't found any way to get this new size before the rotation takes place, and by the time the rotation has happened it's too late as I can't animate the transition of the subviews into their new spots.

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`. As the documentation states:

> By the time this method is called, the interfaceOrientation property is already set to the new orientation. Thus, you can perform any additional layout required by your views in this method.

I believe the view controller's view should also have its new dimensions in this method.

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure out this same problem and I found that the view does not already have its new dimensions. If I set the view's width in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration`, then the view will end up with a status bar sized gap on the side.

Answer (score 1):

Define your `landscape` and `portrait` views in your header, attach them in Interface builder, and try this code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     if(((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
      (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))){

        self.view = landscape;

 }else if(((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || 
     (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))){

        self.view = portrait;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

This is much easier than calculating the new frames for each object in the view.

To animate, you can throw in `[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];` & `[UIView commitAnimations];` to animate to the new view.